# Binding controls from different windows

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I have a textbox in a main window which should display text whenever a user selects an item in a listview.

```
<TextBox Name="txtDoc"  AllowDrop="True" Drop="txtDoc_Drop" Margin="5" />
```

the listview is actually a user control which is placed in the xaml of the main window:

```
<v:ClusterDocumentsView x:Name="cdv" DataContext="{Binding Path=ClusterDocumentsViewModel}" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,10"/>
```

The MouseDown event  in the listview occurs on the user control class, not on the main window.
How can I bind the text box in the main window to the listview which is a user control?

Comment: Are both windows created by the some thread?  (If not thinks get more complex very quickly...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, have the value in question coordinated by your view models if you're doing MVVM. If you're not, you could simply expose another `DependencyProperty` from your `ClusterDocumentsView` that your `TextBox` then binds to.